# Javascript do not react on checkbox with variable id to show hidden Textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

i have a problem with hide and show a textbox based on a checkbox, because it is based on variable ids.

I know that the markActiveLink2(el) function is ok, because i can find the values of the chosen checkbox and textbox with the Console in Chrome.
So for example if i choose the first checkbox the value is CloseDateCheck0.
But somehow the second part of my javascript dont work.

Thank you for your help in advance.

**javascript**

```
 //Hide and Show Close Date

 //Set Variables
 var CloseDateCheck_id = '';
 var CloseDate_id = '';

//Define Variables, so it is known which Date i want to change
 function markActiveLink2(el) {
     CloseDateCheck_id = $(el).attr("id");
     CloseDate_id = CloseDateCheck_id.replace("CloseDateCheck", "CloseDate");
 }

//Hide and show Date based on the variable ids
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#"+ CloseDateCheck_id).click(function () {
     //var $this = $(this);
     if (this.checked) {
         $("#"+CloseDate_id).show();
     } else {
         $("#"+CloseDate_id).hide();
         document.getElementById(CloseDate_id).value = null;
     }
 });
 });
```

**.cshtml**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.OpenIssue.Count(); i++)
{
@*...*@

<b>Close Issue</b>
@Html.CheckBox("Finish", new { id= "CloseDateCheck"+i, onmousedown="markActiveLink2(this);"}) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.OpenIssue[i].CloseDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "datetype", type = "text", style = "width: 90px; display:none", id="CloseDate"+i }) 

@*...*@ 
}
```

**processed html**

```
<b>Close Issue</b>
<input id="CloseDateCheck0" name="Finish" onmousedown="markActiveLink2(this);" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="Finish" type="hidden" value="false">
<input class="datetype hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field CloseDate must be a date." id="CloseDate0" name="OpenIssue[0].CloseDate" style="width: 90px; display:none" type="text" value="">
```

**Solution:**

change javascript to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('[id ^= "CloseDateCheck"]').change(function () {
     if (this.checked) {
         $("#"+CloseDate_id).show();
     } else {
         $("#"+CloseDate_id).hide();
         document.getElementById(CloseDate_id).value = null;
     }
 });
 });
```

Comment: Please add the processed html, rather than .cshtml code

Comment: The selectors is not dynamically evaluated.. You will need to use event delegation

Comment: Use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and give you elements class names - then its simply `$('.finish').change(function() { if ($(this).is(':checked)) { $(this).next('.datetype').show(); } else {... } });`

Answer (score 2):

You are not adding the `click` event to any element on document ready as `CloseDateCheck_Id` is `''`.

try something like this:-

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('[id^="CloseDateCheck"]').change(function() {
     var textbox = $(this).next('[id^="CloseDate"]');
     if (this.checked) {
       textbox.show();
     } else {
       textbox.hide();
       textbox.val(null);
     }
   });
 });
```

This adds a `change` event to all elements which id start with `CloseDateCheck`, then finds the next element for the textbox with id starting with `CloseDate`.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that was almost the solution. I updated the main post with the solution. The textboxes had to be accessed with the specific ids.

Comment: where are you setting `CloseDate_Id`? I cant see how that would work.

Comment: With the javascript. function markActiveLink2(el). The function is connected to the checkbox (onmousedown) and takes the id from it. Eg. CloseDateCheck_id = CloseDateCheck0 if i clicked on the first Checkbox. Then I replace the CloseDateCheck with CloseDate and then i have the id of the CloseDate (eg. CloseDate0). and can use it because i declared it as a global variable. But i dont know if it is bad practice...